# C++ Class that hold an array of another class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

I have a class, let's call it A, and I want to make another class B which will hold n instances of A.

B header file:

```
class A;
class B
{
    B();
    A * arrayofA;
}
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"
B::B() {
 arrayofA = new A[n];
}
```

Visual studio underlines the = operator and tells me:
Error: a value of type "B::A *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "A *"

What's wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you have two classes with the same name, one is global and one is inside class B. It will help if you compile your example to make sure it creates the same error which you are trying to illustrate.

Comment: Also, use `std::vector`.

Comment: I assume you just forgot to copy the `;` after the class declaration, but that this is an otherwise complete example that compiles and demonstrates the problem right? ;)

Comment: "underline" is Intellisense, which is not always correct. The best way to detect compilation errors is to compile and see the output.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the compiler error, it sounds like you accidentally put your pre-declaration inside the scope of B.

The compiler seems to think you are doing this:

```
class B
{
   class A; //It's seeing 'A' inside of 'B'.

   A *arrayOfA;
};
```

It is seeing both a **B::A** and a **::A**. As for why, there's not enough code to know. Check your namespaces and your classes, double-checking where A was pre-declared and where A was actually defined. Check whether they are in the same scope.

You could use a vector to serve the same purpose.

```
#include "A.h"

class B
{
    std::vector<A> array;
}
```

Or if you must have A.h not included, then you can pre-declare A, and define the array as:

```
std::vector< std::unique_ptr<A> > array;
```

Comment: However, he/she said the error is inside B::B (the constructor) where an unqualified A would be the same as B::A.

Comment: I think the class is in the global scope, but the pre-declaration is inside B, so B::A pre-declaration takes precedence over the ::A real class declaration. That's my guess, anyway. More code needs to be visible for us to see what the problem is.